# Search data from a csv file and put it in a spinner

Tags: android, csv, spinner

I'm new at android programming and I need some help..
In my main class I have 2 spinners. One for countries and one for cities. In the first spinner, the user can choose a country. When a country is selected, I would like the second spinner to show the corresponding cities. To do that, I have a .csv file, with countries code (1st column) and cities corresponding (2nd column).

For example, in the first spinner, the user selects CUBA (the corresponding code is CU). Then I want my program to look into my csv file all the lines with "CU" in the first column and take the cities corresponding and print them into the second spinner so that the user can choose a city of Cuba.

My problem is that I don't where I have to put my csv file and how can I program my application to look into it and print my data into the spinner...

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a Service or a Worker Fragment to do all the heavy lifting: open csv, read countries and cities and filter cities given a country. Then create a callback to the Activity showing both spinners to update the UI accordingly. The following components are needed:

1 FragmentActivity to show the spinners. Should have a callback method to receive data updates.

1 Worker Fragment or Service for reading file and broadcasting updates to the FragmentActivity containing the Spinners

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My application is already composed by fragments. My countries'list is already "working". the problem is the cities'list. can you detailed your answer with some code lines because for me the concept is not very clear..thank you

Comment: No problem. The community is here to help.
PS: Don't forget to upvote the correct answer.

Comment: i was wondering if it was possible to put my csv file into the assets folder, and then to open it in my fragment. But I don't really know how to look for data inside the csv file..

Comment: If your countries and cities data will not change, yoy may consider using XML string array resources to store this data and load/filter accordingly.

See
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: This is a possibility but I have almost 200 countries and a lot of cities so doing that will be too long..

Comment: OK. If you have too much data, maybe it is better to read the csv once and save its contents to a database. Then interact with the database and filter its values through queries. In this case, the same components (WorkerFragment/Service and FragmentActivity) could be implemented.

Comment: For now it's not very clear as I don't understand everything on android but I'll try to deal with that.. Thank you again.